# Getting Django for Python 3 Started for Mac django-admin not working

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-admin

I have been trying to set up Django for Python 3 for for 2 days now. I have installed python 3.5.2 on my Mac Mini. I have also have pip3 installed succesfully. I have installed Django using `pip3 install Django`. The problem is that when I try to start my project by typing `django-admin startproject mysite`, I get the error `-bash: django-admin: command not found`. If you need any more info, just let me know, I am also new to Mac so I may be missing something simple. How do I get django-admin working? I have tried pretty much everything I could find on the web.

Comment: are you using a virtual env?

Comment: Yes I am. I installed using `pip3 install virtualenv`

Comment: when you installed django was the virtual env activated, and is it still activated when you try to run `django-admin`?

Comment: No. I even didn't know I had to manually activate the virtual env. Could you tell me what command I should use to activate virtualenv?

Comment: read up http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Comment: I just got virtualenv activated. I tried to run django-admin again, but i get the same `-bash: django-admin: command not found` error.

Comment: I can run the virtual env just fine, I just forgot the command, sorry. But that still leaves the original problem of django-admin not working.

Comment: Have you installed django the virtual env activated?

Comment: Yes, I have installed django and I see the location. Yes, I have activated the virtualenv. I think I have a path issue?

Comment: My mac came with python 2.6, I have installed python 3.5.2 and I want to use that for Django. everything seems to go fine until i try type `django-admin startproject mysite` . Which is why I think it is a path issue. Any thought?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Activate `virtualenv` and install Django there

```
python -m pip install django
```

Try

```
python -m django startproject mysite
```

You can use `python -m django` instead of `django-admin` since Django 1.9.

Answer (score 15):

I am using macport to install python3 and using pip to install Django

```
python3 -m django startproject mysite
```

Answer (score 1):

Create venv at first.

```
python3 -m venv venv
. venv/bin/activate
pip install django
django-admin version
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.

Answer (score 1):

1. make sure the virtual environment is activated, e.g. `source venv/bin/activate` where "venv" is the name of your virtual environment.
2. install django IN this venv -- if you did not do yet
3. run with e.g. `django-admin version` or `python3 -m django startproject ecommerce`